# How can I identify a remote actor?

Tags: scala, actor, remote-actors

I have a remote actor (client) which is registering with another remote actor (server) and then later deregistering (with a shutdown hook). However, although the server picks up the de-registration, the actual **`sender`** property is a *different Channel object*; so in my server logs I have:

> `Registered new client [scala.actors.Channel@158e282]; supporting 1 clients`
>   `De-registered client [scala.actors.Channel@1caf0b6]; supporting 1 clients`

How can I determine (on the server side) that this was the same client actor which originally registered with me? Obviously I could imbue each client with its own `UUID` but I wonder whether there is an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a discussion on the scala users' mailing list, it seems that this is not immediately possible without using some alternative kind of client identifier (like `UUID`). If you send the `self` reference from the client in your registration object, you will get a `ObjectNotSerializable` error.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly add the sender to your message. Use RemoteActor.select to get a scala.actors.remote.Proxy. Use its toString method to identify the sender.